# Trying to change data inside @click inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a v-for loop as my selection for dialog boxes I want to open

```
<v-card @click="page.model = true">
```

page.model is my v-model for a v-dialog

```
  data() {
    return {
      dialog1: false,
      dialog2: false,
      pages: [
        {
          id: "1",
          model: "dialog1",
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          model: "dialog2",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

howcome @click="page.model = true" doesn't work but @click=dialog1 = true " does?
I also tried :@click="page.model = true" and @click="`${page.model}` = true"

Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified, my v-for is: v-for="page in pages"

Comment: You can edit your post to add the v-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we dont see your modal HTML so I presume something like this:

```js
<v-card v-for="page in pages" @click="changePage(page.id)">

<modal v-model="pages[0].isOpen">[CONTAIN OF PAGE 1]</modal>
<modal v-model="pages[1].isOpen">[CONTAIN OF PAGE 2]</modal>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          id: "1",
          model: "dialog1",
          isOpen: false,
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          model: "dialog2",
          isOpen: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  methods: {
    changePage(id) {
      // close all other modal page
      this.pages.each(el => el.isOpen = false);

      // open the good one
      const index = this.pages.findIndex(el => el.id == id);
      this.pages[index].isOpen = true;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. Call a method and pass index of item. In the method you can then access the specific model via index

```
<v-card @click="updateDialog(index)">

updateDialog(i): {
  this.pages[i].model = true
}
```